How can a laywoman find the ‘established jurisprudence’ against ‘repeated requests for accommodation’ on CanLII?
In Tang v. McMaster University, 2015 HRTO 551 (CanLII), [81], Vice-chair Jo-Anne Pickel failed to cite any case law.

Was the Decision in conflict with established jurisprudence by requiring the applicant to make repeated requests for accommodation?
[81]        Finally, I do not agree with the applicant that the Decision conflicts with established jurisprudence by requiring persons with disabilities to make numerous and repeated requests for accommodation and to continue making such requests even after an education service provider has denied certain accommodations.

How can a laywoman, like me, do this?  I searched "repeated requests"  "duty to accommodate" disability, with 191 results. Doubtless, it’s unworkable to read 191 documents.
Then I searched "repeated requests for accommodation". I perused all 8 search results, but none cited this “established jurisprudence”.
